# How to fix this issue: "Invalid Host Header" in vue3 app hosted with GCP cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, vuejs3

I tried to deploy vue3 app with Github and GCP-cloud-run.
But using the Url built with GCP-cloud-run to enter web page, error occurs with "Invalid Host Header".
[the Url built with with GCP-cloud-run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJFaK.png)
[running app with the built Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C9o3.png)

My vue3 app is running well on localhost:8080 without error.
[localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZHWS.png)
If you have experience, please help me.